# How to position divs correctly in a for loop in PHP and CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have an issue I have been trying to solve. I have created a "blog" you can call it, and I have the option to make a new post. When I make a new post, a div is added. However, when the div gets added, the previous post is shifted to the right. I have tried all sorts of suggestions, but I can't get it. Here is an image:

[image: Divs being added not being placed properly.]

What I want is so that the divs are lined up properly. Here is my code:

```css
body {

 

 background-color: #558C89;

 /*background-color: #1FDA9A;*/

 color: #000305; /*remove if background is not working */

 font-size: 87.5%; /*base font size is 14px */

 font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';

 line-height: 1.5;

 text-align: left;

 margin-left: 21.5%;

 

 

}

a {

 text-decoration: none;

}



a:link, a:visited {

 

}



a:hover, a:active {

 

}



.body {

 

 

 

}



form { 



display: inline; 



}

#logo {

 

 position: absolute;

 z-index: 1;

 left: 0;

 top: 5px;

 height: 50px;

 vertical-align: top;

 

 



 

}



.mainheader img {

  

  width: 100%;

  height: auto;

  margin: 0% 0%;



}



.mainheader nav {

  background-color: #424242;

  /*background-color: #008BBA; /* Here for color of navigated buttons*/

  height: 65px;

  width: 100%;

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  left: 0;

  border-radius: 5px;

  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

  border-style: solid;

  border-color: black;

  border-width: 1px;

 

}



.mainheader nav ul {

 

 list-style: none;

 margin: 0 auto;

 

}



.mainheader nav ul li {

 

 float: right;

 display: inline;

 margin-top: 0px;

 

}



.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {

 

 color: #FFF;

 font-weight: bold;

 display: inline-block;

 padding: 18px 25px;

 height: 10px;

 /* Come back here to continue to edit buttons */

}



.mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active, .mainheader nav .active a:link,

.mainheader nav .active a:visited {

 

 background-color: #638CA6;

 opacity: 0.85;

 height: 63px;

 text-shadow: none;

 

 

}



.mainheader nav ul li a {

 

 border-radius: 5px;

 -moz-border-radius: 5px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

 

}



.newsClass{

 position: absolute;

 width: 1000px;

 background-color: #404040;

 border-style: solid;

 border-color: black;

 border-width: 1px;

 text-align: center;

 color: #FFF;

 margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;

 top: 25%;

 left: 27%;

 z-index: 2;

 

 

}

.topcontent {

 background-color: #404040;

 width: 850px;

 position: absolute;

 text-align: center;

 color: #FFF;

 margin-top: 120px;

 border-style: solid;

 border-color: black;

 border-width: 1px;

 line-height: 1;

 display: inline-block;

 

 left: 21.5%;

 

}





#box{

    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);

    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 5px 5px 2px;

    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.1);

    border-radius: 4px;

    top:50px;

}



h2{

    text-align:center;

    color:#fff;

}



#footer {

 

 color: #FFF;

 

}
```

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include("blog.php");


$posts = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? get_posts($_GET['id']) : get_posts();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];



?>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Home</title>
  
  
        <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="accountCSS/myaccountStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS/style.css">
  
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.gif">

    </head>

    <body>
 

  <a href="www.cookeh.org"><img src="images/logo.gif" id="logo"/></a>
 <header class="mainheader">
  <nav><ul>
  
   
   <?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo '<li><a href="logout">Log out</a></li>';
    }else{
    echo '<li><a href="login">Log in</a></li>';
    }
   ?>
   <li><a href="myaccount">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
   <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
  
  </ul></nav>
  
 </header>

 <h2 class="newsClass"> Recent News <?php if(getPermissions($username)) {echo '<a href="add_post.php", style="color:green">New Post</a>'; }?>
</h2>       
   <?php
     
     foreach($posts as $post) {
      
      ?>
        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">
         
            <div class="inner-bg">
                <div class="container">
           
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                         <div class="form-top">
                          <div class="form-top-left">
         

      <h2 class ="title"><a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id'];?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $post['title'];?></a></h2>
      <p> Posted on <?php echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s', strtotime($post['date_posted'])); ?>
       in <a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $post['category_id']; ?>", style="color:green"><?php echo $post['name']; ?></a>
      
     
       <br></br>

            
       
      <?php
      
      if(getPermissions($username)) {
       
       ?>
       
         <a href="edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>", style="color:green">Edit Post |</a>
       

      <a href="delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>", style="color:green"> Delete Post</a>
       
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </p>
      <div class="contents"> <?php echo nl2br($post['contents']); ?></div>
      
      

      <?php
     }
     
     ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-top-right">
                           
                          </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
              
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
        
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
 
 <script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-88077370-1', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');

 </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

NOTE: I guess the "run snipped" doesn't seem to run php.

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Include the rendered HTML and remove the PHP tag.

Comment: @miken32 I think it did turn out to be a PHP question.

Comment: @bedtime21 Basically just move the closing bracket for the `foreach` loop after the last closing div. Also, don't put commas between your attributes, and `<br>` should not have a `</br>`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah that was the issue, didn't realize I had to put them after the divs, thank you!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Do you know of a way to decrement the posts? As in, move them down each time. Now they just overlap eachother, what would be the right css to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not closing the divs in the correct places.

Make sure your indentation is correct and ensure that every `<div>` you open inside the `foreach` is also closed before the `foreach` is closed.

I like to use `foreach():` `endforeach;` when you have a lot of markup inside a loop like this, as it makes reading the code a lot easier.

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post):?>
<div>
    <h2 class ="title">
       <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id'];?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $post['title'];?></a>
    </h2>
    <p> 
        Posted on 
        <?php echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s', strtotime($post['date_posted'])); ?>
        in 
        <a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $post['category_id']; ?>", style="color:green">
            <?php echo $post['name']; ?>
        </a>
        <br></br>
        <?php if(getPermissions($username)): ?>

            <a href="edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>", style="color:green">Edit Post |</a>

            <a href="delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>", style="color:green"> Delete Post</a>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <div class="contents"> 
      <?php echo nl2br($post['contents']); ?></div>
    <div>

</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Adding a wrapping div to each post will provide a box around the markup inside. Divs have display:block be default. It is better practice than using `<br />` or `<p>&nsbp;</p>` as it will give you more control when/if you need to style that element.

Comment: Thank you, I now just have the posts overlapping each other, is there a way to increment them downwards? It makes sense to have the divs before the loop closes!

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure what you mean by incrementing them downwards. Do you want to add `margin-bottom` to each post? If you post what you post what your html looks like now I should be able to help

Comment: Oh, what I meant is that the posts currently overlap each other now. I want whenever there is a new post, I want the older post to go beneath the newer post. As of now, they are just overlapping each other. The html is the same as above, but with the closing bracket for the loop is moved after the last div. Here is an image of what I mean: http://imgur.com/a/Y9cOG

Comment: Add `<br />` after last `</div>` that display yours code block in foreach that will bring every post for itself, and you problem is probably in css.